# User connected to same Router are not showing up in Network tab

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I wanna limit Internet speed of my WiFi users. I am doing this through a software Called "SelfishNet". But I can't see other networks connected in the "Network List".

Screenshot URL : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDdxp.png

Comment: `Selfishnet exploits a very old technique called ARP cache poisoning, to convince all other nodes on your LAN that your own machine is the default gateway. After this, all their Internet-bound traffic will be sent to your box instead of their intended destination, and only you will have real Internet access.` It could be that the exploit doesn't work anymore or there is security software on the pc's which aren't fooled anymore by this exploit. Use the method suggested by Wayne and get a quality router in which you can manage the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throttling or Limiting Bandwidth is normally only achieved by changing configuration of the Router or Access Point through which the users connect.

I would be very dubious of that software, I'm unsure if its capable of what it claims.

Answer (score -2):

selfishnet discovery process is done through arp. but in public networks for instance ( say at Starbucks ) there is a feature enabled called client isolation where clients are not aware of each other.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).